# Php send form details to email address

Tags: php

```
Email:    Input type.    email.     name.    email
Username:    input type.   text    name.    username
Password:    input type.   password.   name.   password
Confirm password:     input type.    password.    name.   c_password
```

Please how do I send this form details email,username,password and confirm password to an email address?

Comment: Hi, have you tried something on your own? If so, do please include it in the question. SO is ***NOT a free coding service*** nor a **teach me*** place.

Comment: Epodax is right, this is not a "code me a whole website for free"-community. There are plenty of tutorials how-to send form-data via e-mail which you can almost copy&paste since what you're trying to achieve is very basic. But to help you out atleast a bit, here's a tutorial which seems ok for your purpose: [Tutorial howto send form data via mail](http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-form-to-email.html)

Comment: Look at a php email library, download it and follow the examples. If you have trouble using it, send a quetion with your problems.

Comment: @Bubu why should I work for free? Pay me 200$ and I'd be happy to "gibbe my code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a form that looks something like this:

```
<form method='POST' action='your_script.php'>
 <input type='email' name='email'>
 <input type='text' name='username'>
 <input type='password' name='password'>
 <input type='password' name='c_password'>
 <input type='submit' value='Send'>
</form>
```

After you enter the data in the input fields and send the form,your data will be sent to the script that you've placed in the form action atribute `<form action='your_script.php'>`.
In `your_script.php` insert this part of code:

```
<?php
 //your_script.php
 $to="example@domain.com";
 $subject="Your mail title";
 $message="Email: ".$_POST['email']." ,username: ".$_POST['username'].", 
 password: ".$_POST['password']." ,confirmed password: ".$_POST['c_password'];

mail($to,$subject,$message);
?>
```

mail() function is pretty simple to use,but sometimes the function doesn't work because the mail servers usually require SMTP authentication.
There are some decent solutions for this slight problem,feel free to google about it.